# Switching on non-Ints in Java

Tags: java

I'm having trouble figuring out the inner workings of switches in Java
I'm told that for all primitives, the value is promoted to a Integer.

However, in the following example, I'm testing on a byte variable, and any case larger than 127 will not compile:

```
byte k = 5;
switch(k){
  case 128:    //fails to compile, possible loss of precision
```

I realize this is an error and have no issue with that. My question is:
How does the JVM track that it's switching on a byte if it takes the value of "k" and promotes it to an integer before testing each case?

Comment: I'm not concerned with the compilation error, that is only an example. Is it the case that the switched variable is NOT promoted to an integer?

Comment: It is promoted, see my answer or JVM spec Section 7.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is it's not promoting the value of k, it's trying to take the case statement (128 - signed integer) and assign it to a byte. As 128 is larger than 1 byte (7 bits + sign bit) then the compilation fails.

For example

```
byte k = 128;
```

would also fail to compile.
 See the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.11)

Comment: I realize that part. My question is if the value being switch upon is promoted to an integer, how does the JVM track what it's true type really is

Comment: The value being switched upon (e.g. k) is not promoted to an integer, Rather the case constants are attempted to be interpreted as the type of the value being switched upon (e.g. byte). (does that make sense?)

Comment: You're saying if somehow the value becomes an integer? Which won't happen, because you've defined it as a byte?

Answer (score 9):

The `switch` statement is not limited to `int`.  The Java Language Specification (JLS), [section 14.11, The switch Statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.11), states

> The type of the Expression must be char, byte, short, int, Character,
>   Byte, Short, Integer, or an enum type, or a compile-time error occurs.

Your `byte`, therefore, is not promoted to an `int`.  The JLS goes on to say that what you are doing will cause a compile-time error:

> Every case constant expression associated with a switch statement must
>   be assignable to the type of the switch Expression.

...since 128 is not assignable to a `byte`.

Answer (score 2):

It is not compiling because:

**Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte**

Which is obvious because your k is of type `byte` and literal 128 is an int as per Java rule.

If you change case statement to:

```
case (byte) 128:
```

then it will **compile** without any error.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to cast to `byte`:

```
switch(k) {
    case (byte) 128:
}
```

That's fine - the problem was just that there isn't an implicit conversion from the literal 128 to `byte`. You get the same problem with simple assignment:

```
// Invalid
byte a = 128;

// Valid
byte b = (byte) 128;
```

The value of `b` will *actually* be -128, as 128 is outside the range of a Java `byte` - but the bit pattern is correct, so in many cases this is what you want; it's also the value that would hit the case given above in the switch statement.

Answer (score 1):

The Java Spec says:

> Every case constant expression associated with a switch statement must be assignable (§5.2) to the type of the switch Expression.

The JVM Spec says that the type is promoted, but that is a different (not compile time) matter.

Answer (score 0):

byte is of size -128 to 127 only. when you are passing byte as switch case, it is precision lose and highlights compile time required byte, found int error. byte (128) will resolve the issue.

Comment: And it's the wrong answer anyway...the `byte` is not promoted.